# How to make perl recognize a string with several | 's in it as a single string?

Tags: regex, string, perl, replace, large-files

I am a complete amateur at perl, and I would like to ask a question to assist me on a find and replace function that I am trying to apply to change the Reference Names on a SAM file so I can run it through FindPeaks. The files are far to large (from 5 to 17 gigs) for me to be able to open them in a text editor and run the match without using a programming language.

Basically, I want perl to match an entire string such as "gi|149288852|ref|NC_000067.5|NC_000067" and replace the whole the whole thing only with "chr1".

However, so far I can only seem to make it either replace it with "chr1|chr1|chr1|chr1|chr1" or "gi|chr1|ref|NC000067.g|NC_000067"

Can anyone help me out?

Edit:

I've tried a few different things, but what I'm trying to do is modify a program my supervisor got from someone to do this correctly, I'll post it below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %Chr = (

    "gi|149288852|ref|NC_000067.5|NC_000067" => "chr1",
    "gi|149288869|ref|NC_000076.5|NC_000076" => "chr10",
    "gi|149288871|ref|NC_000077.5|NC_000077" => "chr11",
    "gi|149292731|ref|NC_000078.5|NC_000078" => "chr12",
    "gi|149292733|ref|NC_000079.5|NC_000079" => "chr13",
    "gi|149292735|ref|NC_000080.5|NC_000080" => "chr14",
    "gi|149301884|ref|NC_000081.5|NC_000081" => "chr15",
    "gi|149304713|ref|NC_000082.5|NC_000082" => "chr16",
    "gi|149313536|ref|NC_000083.5|NC_000083" => "chr17",
    "gi|149321426|ref|NC_000084.5|NC_000084" => "chr18",
    "gi|149323268|ref|NC_000085.5|NC_000085" => "chr19",
    "gi|149338249|ref|NC_000068.6|NC_000068" => "chr2",
    "gi|149352351|ref|NC_000069.5|NC_000069" => "chr3",
    "gi|149354223|ref|NC_000070.5|NC_000070" => "chr4",
    "gi|149354224|ref|NC_000071.5|NC_000071" => "chr5",
    "gi|149361431|ref|NC_000072.5|NC_000072" => "chr6",
    "gi|149361432|ref|NC_000073.5|NC_000073" => "chr7",
    "gi|149361523|ref|NC_000074.5|NC_000074" => "chr8",
    "gi|149361524|ref|NC_000075.5|NC_000075" => "chr9",
    "gi|149361525|ref|NC_000086.6|NC_000086" => "chrX",
    "gi|149361526|ref|NC_000087.6|NC_000087" => "chrY", 
    );

my $usage = "\n\n\tUsage: convert.pl <SAM file>\n\nThis script converts NCBI ref#s to chr #s\n\n";

die $usage unless ( @ARGV == 1);

my $file = $ARGV[0];

open (IN, "$file") or die "Can't open file: $file\n";

while (<IN>){

    if (/\S+\s+\d+\s+(gi\S+)/){

    my $tag = $1;
    if (exists $Chr{$tag}){
        my $line = $_;
        $line =~ s/'$tag'/$Chr{$tag}/;
        print $line;
    }
    else {
        die "\n\n\nHash value doesn't exist for $tag $_\n\n";
    }
    }
    else {

    print $_;
    }
}
```

Which comes out with the: "gi|chr1|ref|NC000067.g|NC_000067"

I've also tried this:

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/gi|149288852|ref|NC_000067.5|NC_000067/chr1/g;' *.sam
```

to see if I could do it one by one, but that comes out with the "chr1|ch1|chr1|chr1|chr1"

Comment: Sounds like a greedy / non-greedy matching issue?

Comment: Can you include the regex that you're using?

Comment: the fat comma automatically quotes the lvalue, so you don't need `"gi|149361526|ref|NC_000087.6|NC_000087" => "chrY"`, you should just have `gi|149361526|ref|NC_000087.6|NC_000087 => "chrY"`

Comment: @JohnCorbett: If he wants to quote the left-hand side, that's perfectly ok; besides, it has nothing to do with the problem at hand...

Comment: @JohnCorbett, he must quote the left operand in this case.  Otherwise, perl will parse the pipes as logical OR operators between barewords and other literals.

Comment: are you sure? I thought the fat comma just quoted it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem is:

```
$line =~ s/'$tag'/$Chr{$tag}/;
```

Your `$tag` still contains the meta-characters.

Use:

```
$line =~ s/\Q$tag/$Chr{$tag}/;
```